# Jenkins - Local checkout - Enable using script console

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am encountering below error. I am able to set the property using `System.setProperty("hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT", "true")`

However, the issue still persists. Any pointers?

```
ERROR: Checkout of Git remote '<path to project folder>' aborted
because it references a local directory, which may be insecure.
You can allow local checkouts anyway by setting the system property
'hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT' to true.
```

Comment: How are you running / how did you install Jenkins?

Answer (score 2):

As per https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-68571:

it seems the System Property is read during initialization, thus changing it in Script Console does not change it.

In Script console use property on class directly:

```
hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT = true
```

Note that neither the System Property nor the class property persist across restarts.

A persistent solution depends on how you installed / start Jenkins.

If you are running via `java -jar ...`, add the system property there (`java -Dhudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT=true -jar ...`).

Or, if you installed it using your systems package manager and your system is using systemd:

```
$ sudo systemctl edit jenkins
 
[Service]
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Dhudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT=true"
 
$ sudo systemctl restart jenkins
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the info I needed and propably helps you too in
https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-68571:

So, follow these steps:

```
$ sudo systemctl stop jenkins
$ sudo systemctl edit jenkins

[Service]
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP= -Dhudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.ALLOW_LOCAL_CHECKOUT=true"

$ sudo systemctl restart jenkins
```

Comment: What if I am using Windows?